# Compress and get thumbnails from .mp4 files using .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ffmpeg

I was searching how we can compress mp4 file and generate thumbnails from that file, Fortunately, I found one solution **"MediaToolKit"** that worked perfectly for thumbnail generation but not works for compression.

Currently, what I am doing, I have generated .bat file which contains commands of FFmpeg for example

**ffmpeg -i %1 -an -crf 25 -vf  fps=fps=30,scale=640x480  %output.mp4**

But it's not good stuff, I want to write a program in C# which will take video and compress it and generate thumbnails

Does anyone have an idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FFMpegCore library.

```
Nuget: Install-Package FFMpegCore
```

After Installing the package you have to download binaries from here [ffbinaries](https://ffbinaries.com/downloads).
To change the root directory path make use of this:

```
public Startup() 
{
   FFMpegOptions.Configure(new FFMpegOptions { RootDirectory = "./bin" });
}
```

these are all refer into github [vladjerca/FFMpegCore](https://github.com/vladjerca/FFMpegCore)

To make the compression:

```
Startup();
string inputFile = @"yourVideoPath.mp4";
var encoder = new FFMpeg();
FileInfo outputFile = new FileInfo(@"newVideo.mp4");
var video = VideoInfo.FromPath(inputFile);
//track conversion progress
encoder.OnProgress += (percentage) => Console.WriteLine("Progress {0}%", percentage);
encoder.Convert(
      video,
      outputFile,
      VideoType.Mp4,
      Speed.UltraFast,
      VideoSize.Ld,
      AudioQuality.Low,
      true);
```

Answer (score 1):

After doing a lot of searches I found MediaToolKit is the best option for this because
it giving the option for custom command

To compress video through a custom command
For example

```
  using (var engine = new Engine(@"C:\ffmpeg.exe"))
  {
     int crf = 23;
     string resolution = "960:720";
     string command = string.Format(@"-i {0} -vf scale={1} -c:v libx264 -preset 
     ultrafast -r 30 -crf {2} {3}", input, resolution, crf, output);

     engine.CustomCommand(command);
   }
```

To get thumbnails it has method

```
engine.GetThumbnail() // it will take 3 arguments inputFile, outputFile, conversionOptions
```